# How to retrieve original text after using htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities()

Tags: php, database, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I have some text that I will be saving to my DB. Text may look something like this: `Welcome & This is a test paragraph`. When I save this text to my DB after processing it using `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` in PHP, the sentence will look like this: `Welcome &amp; This is a test paragraph`.

When I retrieve and display the same text, I want it to be in the original format. How can I do that?

This is the code that I use;

```
$text= htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($_POST['text'])); 
$text= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text);
```

Comment: `html_entity_decode` is counterpart of `htmlentities`, by the way: better change your sql to use prepared statement and bind `$_POST['text']` as it is to the query. I thing you do to mutch on the original data.

Comment: Why are doing this?  Insert the data unchanged and modify for it's purpose, display etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, you are double-encoding HTML characters by using both `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars`. Both of those functions do the same thing, but `htmlspecialchars` only does it with a subset of characters that have HTML character entity equivalents (the *special* ones.) So with your example, the ampersand would be encoded twice (since it *is* a special character), so what you would actually get would be:

```
$example = 'Welcome &amp; This is a test paragraph';

$example = htmlentities($example);
var_dump($example);    // 'Welcome &amp; This is a test paragraph'

$example = htmlspecialchars($example);
var_dump($example);    // 'Welcome &amp;amp; This is a test paragraph'
```

Decide which one of those functions you need to use (probably `htmlspecialchars` will be sufficient) and use only one of them.

Second, you are using these functions at the wrong time. `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` will not do anything to *"sanitize"* your data for input into your database. (Not saying that's what you're intending, as you haven't mentioned this, but many people do seem to try to do this.) If you want to protect yourself from SQL injection, [bind your values to prepared statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples) Escaping it as you are currently doing with `mysqli_real_escape_string` is good, but it isn't really sufficient.

`htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` have specific purposes: to convert characters in strings that you are going to output into an HTML document. Just wait to use them until you are ready to do that.